# Swift: UITableView not loading data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, delegates

I have two view controllers `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. `SecondViewController` is a normal view controller with a `UITableView` on it.

From the `FirstViewController` I call the second to appear. When I call it I want to pass data via a delegate.
The delegate protocol is as follows:

```
protocol CalculationDelegate{
    func calculations(calculation: [Double])
}
```

Basically it is passing an array of doubles. When A button is clicked on `FirstViewController` I use  `prepareForSegue` to get ready for the transition and set up the delegate.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var secondVC = SecondViewController()
    secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController

    // Set up the delegation, so data is passed to SecondViewController
    self.delegate = SecondViewController()
    self.delegate?.calculations(wage.allCalculations)
}
```

Now in the `SecondViewController` I want to access the data I have just passed to be loaded on the `UITableView`.
Here is the full class declaration of `SecondViewController`

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CalculationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet
    var tableView: UITableView!
    var calculations: [Double] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    // Conform to CalculationsDelegate by implementing this method
    func calculations(calculation: [Double]) {
        self.calculations = calculation

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.calculations.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", self.calculations[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

}
```

As you can see I am trying to assign `self.calculations = calculation` in the delegates method. Then use that as the data to load the `UITableView` with, however, the data will not load. I have error checked and the data is being passed from the delegate. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SecondViewController()`  actually contructs a new instance of the view controller. Lets look at your code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var secondVC = SecondViewController() // Line 1
    secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController()  // Line 2

    // Set up the delegation, so data is passed to SecondViewController()
    self.delegate = SecondViewController()  // Line 3
    self.delegate?.calculations(wage.allCalculations)
}
```

Take a look at Line1. You are creating a new instance of the the `SecondViewController` in secondVC which is not required.

Line 2 - This line is required to take instance of the `destinationViewController` of the segue.

Line 3 = This line you are again creating another instance which is not required. You are setting the `calculations array` on this instance. The segue works on another instance. which is why you don't get the array inside the second view controller.

This following code should work.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController()

    secondVC.calculations(wage.allCalculations)
}
```

I don't see why you need a delegate and a protocol just to set the calculations array. Just defining the `calculations` function in SecondViewController is enough.